The universe is critically dense - now or always?
The density of the current universe is very close to critical - that's why it’s flat. However, the flatness problem arises because from the First Friedman Equation we can show that if the universe is very close to critically dense at the end of the radiation dominated era, it must have been much more closer to begin with (unless we consider inflation). However, in a radiation dominated universe $\rho\propto a^{-4}$, leading to $\frac{\rho _c}{\rho}-1 \propto a^2$. In a matter dominated universe the deviation streching rate is lower, $\frac{\rho _c}{\rho}-1 \propto a$, while in a dark energy dominated universe it actually shrinks, since $\frac{\rho _c}{\rho}-1 \propto a^{-2}$. So, if we observe the universe is critically dense Now, it actually means it was less close to critically dense at the end of the matter dominated era - countering the flatness problem. For the flatness problem to actually be a problem, either the countering effect must be insufficient or the universe must be critically dense during or before the matter dominated era.
So, which one happened? What does the far away (therefore past) experimental data say?

If it's critically dense now it was always critically dense, the Hubble parameter changes accordingly to satisfy
$$\rm H^2=\frac{8 \ \pi \ G \ \rho}{3}+\frac{k \ c^2}{a^2}$$
no matter which value $\rm \rho$ changes to over time. If we now have critical density $\rm \rho_{c}=3 \ H^2/(8 \ \pi \ G)$ that means the curvature $\rm k=1/\surd r_k=0$, which means an infinite radius of curvature $\rm r_k=\infty$, which in other words is a flat universe which was and will always be flat.
If it is just a measurement problem, meaning that $\rm k \approx 0$ only within the margins of error while the true value is slightly different, the radius of curvature $\rm r_k$ would get larger (closer to flat) proportional to the scale factor $\rm a$ when you go forward in time, which would blow up the curvature $\rm k$ proportional to $\rm 1/a^2$ the farther you go back in time.

This was the point of the OPs question. If you forget dark energy a closed universe gets more closed and an open umiverse gets more open. I can't follow your last paragraph. What does "blow up the curvature proportional to $1/a^2$ mean.  $1/a^2$ is getting snaller.

@ProfRob wrote: »What does "blow up the curvature proportional to 1/a² mean. 1/a² is getting smaller.« - it's getting smaller as a and t get larger, therefore I wrote it blows up »the farther you go back in time«, in the future it gets smaller.

Well - the universe is not absolutely flat - it's very close to being flat. In FLRW metric k remains constant. To keep it constant the universe does not need to be always critically dense, even though it is now. Actually that's how inflation solves the flatness problem - avoiding the necessity of the universe being critically dense to begin with.
